# Write the equation of a second-order line $2x^2-12xy-7y^2+8x+6y=0$ in canonical form

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Write the equation of a second-order line $$2x^2-12xy-7y^2+8x+6y=0$$ in canonical form.

To find its center, we have the following system of equations:
$$2x-6y+4=0, \\ -6x-7y+3=0.$$
Hence, the center is at $\big(-\frac{1}{5},\frac{3}{5}\big)$. However, I don't know how to continue?

Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recenter the curve $2x^2-12xy-7y^2+8x+6y=0$ to origin with $x\to x-\frac15$ and $y\to y+\frac35$

$$2x^2-12xy-7y^2+1=0$$

Then, rotate the axes $\theta$ degrees with $ \cos\theta= \frac1{\sqrt5}$ and $ \sin\theta= \frac2{\sqrt5}$, which corresponds to $x\to \frac1{\sqrt5}x - \frac2{\sqrt5}y$ and $x\to \frac2{\sqrt5}x +\frac1{\sqrt5}y$ to obtain the canonical equation

$$\frac{x^2}{\frac1{10}}-\frac{y^2}{\frac1{5}}=1
$$

Edit: Determine angle of rotation

Note that the equations of the asymptotes are $2x^2-12xy-7y^2=0$, with their slopes $m_1+m_2=-\frac{12}7$ and $m_1m_2=-\frac{2}7$. Then, the angle $\theta$ of the major exit can be obtained from

$$ \tan2\theta = \frac{m_1+m_2}{1-m_1m_2}=-\frac43$$

which yields $\tan\theta=2$, hence $\cos\theta= \frac1{\sqrt5}$ and $ \sin\theta= \frac2{\sqrt5}$

Comment: Thanks! How to find $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$?

Comment: @VIVID - see the edit in the answer

Comment: Understandable, thanks! Could you please, suggest some books to learn better? I'm not satisfied with my own book.

Comment: @VIVID - I have not come across a dedicated book on advanced conics. Some problems here are really good, along with some equally good answers. If you keep taking notes while going through them, you could learn quite some over time

Answer (score 1):

$$2x^2-12xy +8x-7y^2+6y=2(x-3y+2)^2-(3y-2)^2-7y^2+6y=$$

$$=2(x-3y+2)^2-16y^2+18y-4=2(x-3y+2)^2-16\left(y-\frac9{16}\right)^2+\frac{81}{16}-4=$$

$$=2(x-3y+2)^2-16\left(y-\frac9{16}\right)^2+\frac{17}4=0$$

Change variables and you get the equation:

$$\begin{cases}x':=x-3y+2\\{}\\
y':=y-\frac9{16}\end{cases}\;\;\implies2x'^2-16y'^2=-\frac{17}4\implies\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{17}}8\right)^2}-\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{17}}{\sqrt{8}}\right)^2}=1$$

So it is a hyperbola, as you can see...a vertical one, in fact ( thus the original one is a slanted vertical-ish one ).

And you are right: the center of the original hyperbola is what you wrote

Comment: If we care about reading off $a,b$:  $\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt{5}}&\frac2{\sqrt{5}}\\\frac2{\sqrt{5}}&-\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&-6\\-6&-7\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt{5}}&\frac2{\sqrt{5}}\\\frac2{\sqrt{5}}&-\frac1{\sqrt{5}}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-10&0\\0&5\end{pmatrix}$

$$10\,\left(\frac{2\,\left(y-\frac{3}{5}\right)}{\sqrt{5}}+\frac{
 x+\frac{1}{5}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2-5\,\left(\frac{2\,\left(x+\frac{
 1}{5}\right)}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{y-\frac{3}{5}}{\sqrt{5}}\right)^2=1$$ i.e. $a=\frac1{\sqrt{10}},b=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}$

Comment: Thank you. Why did you omit primes ($'$) in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can rotate the $x$-$y$ axis as [Jan-Magnus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/28956/jan-magnus-%c3%98kland) does with the rotate transform formula from $x$-$y$ to $u$-$v$ :
$$
\bigg(
\begin{array}{c}
u \\
v
\end{array}
\bigg)
=
\bigg(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta \, \sin \theta\\
-\sin \theta \, \cos \theta
\end{array}
\bigg)
\bigg(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\bigg)
$$
substitute $x$,$y$ with linear form of $u$,$v$,then eliminate the cross-product item $u*v$ with its coefficient equals $0$, and so on.

Alternatively  you can also let 
$$
\begin{cases}
u = a x - b y + m, \\
v = b x + a y + n.
\end{cases}
$$ 
then eliminate $u*v$ as well and extrapolate $a,b,m,n$ also get what you want.